# How to replace a static method call to an instance method call using Javassist?

Tags: java, javassist

I want to use Javassist to translate something like `SomeClass.get(foo, "bar")` to `foo.bar()`.

I looked into `ExprEditor` and I tried something like:

```
private static class StaticToInstanceAccessorConverter extends ExprEditor {
    @Override
    void edit(MethodCall methodCall) throws CannotCompileException {
        if (methodCall.className.equals('my.package.Somaclass') && Modifier.isStatic(methodCall.method.getModifiers())) {
            if (methodCall.methodName.equals('get')) {
                methodCall.replace('{ $_ = $1.$2(); }')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```

but this does not seem to work? Any hint would be welcome!

Comment: You should make it a little clearer that you're working with the javassist library.

Comment: Could it be because `"bar"` is a String?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that but I didn't find a way to modify that